# Select Current Month folder in filepath

Tags: excel, directory, subdirectory, vba

I am looking for a way to select the current month's folder and open a specific file where the current month folder is located in a folder named "2017" and includes all 12 months' folders.

I can already go directly to a specific folder but trying to write a code that let's a user go to the 2017 folder then the code locates the current month's folder and Calls Reject_Review.  File type is not important as it may be a .csv, .xlsx, .xlsm depending on what we decide.

The code below is what I'm using to try to locate the current month folder.  This a folder path on a shared drive.

```
Sub CurrentMonthFolderOpenFile() 


Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

If Len(Dir("E:xxx_xxSolutions\xxx - xx Governance\xxx Controls\xxx Monitoring\Monthly xxx Review\MonthName(Month(Date), False), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then Call Reject_Review

End If 

End Sub
```

Comment: you forgot to close the string

Comment: Thanks, Edd.  I changed  "False" to "True" and it is working.

Comment: Cool, but the string is still left open :) I would suggest you edit your question  with the following (review it, make sure it works):

Len(Dir("E:xxx_xxSolutions\xxx - xx Governance\xxx Controls\xxx Monitoring\Monthly xxx Review\" & MonthName(Month(Now()), True), vbDirectory))